# Adding New column to existing Dataframe using Numpy Array Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code

```
for output_label in OUTPUT_COLUMN:
    df_train.loc[:, output_label + "_orig"] = y_train
    df_train.loc[:, output_label + "_pred"] = y_train
    df_test.loc[:, output_label + "_orig"]  = y_test
    df_test.loc[:, output_label + "_pred"]  = y_test
```

This works fine when there is only one dimension in the `y_train` and `y_test`. But when there are two dimension in the arrays, the above code keeps repeating the values in the other columns.

Please let me know what is the best possible method that can add new column values using the numpy array irrespective of the dimension.

I have output columns as `['A', 'B', 'C']` and numpy array look like: `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly but if you wanna assign **multiple columns** to a DataFrame using a **multi-dimensional** array, that's the way:

```
df[['A','B','C']]=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
```

Comment: No there is a problem. If my `OUTPUT_COLUMN = ['A', 'B', 'C']`,  then the DF column name I am using is = `['A_orig', 'B_orig', 'C_orig']` and `['A_pred', 'B_pred', 'C_pred']`. There is the issue coming. As I have to place the data separately and without losing its relevance. Currently I am initiating so using the same data but later they are going to get filled with `pred` data.